# Microservice architecture for projects with low budgets / little traffic

Tags: microservices

When implementing a microservice architecture and keeping services really small, you soon have many services, let's say 100 for simplicity. Now when deploying each service to an AWS nano instance, this would cost ~500$ / month, a rather hefty sum for a smaller project or a hobby developer. **What options do I have to reduce this price, while still being able to have many services?**

I thought about putting multiple services on one nano instance (maybe dockerized). I can comfortably fit ~5 services on one nano instance, so the price would be 5 times lower. The problem I have with this, is that I have to manage a lot of things and it doesn't seem to scale well. Is there a better way or alternatively a web-service that does this for me?

Comment: To ease  the management hazzle you could go for CoreOS or Tectonix. You could still have EC2 instances or ans other IAAS but run said programs on them

Answer (score 4):

**Microservices as a tool**

One thing you may want to think about is if microservices are an architecture for a small project with low traffic.

Microservices architecture is a tool to solve e.g. high traffic challenges and with low traffic a monolith may be a more cost effective approach. Microservices come also at a cost (complexity all over the board - design, deployment, service discovery and relations).

Keep in mind that your microservices shouldn't be too small and as per the best practices you should cover a single domain with them (https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html), not split a business domain into multiple microservices just for the sake of having microservices (unless this is a training project where you want to learn the tools for microservices architecture).

I am not sure how large solution you would need to have to have a challenge of 100 microservices, but maybe you should review their design and make sure that they are not too small :)

Nice and short article about this topic - [Microservice Architectures: What They Are and Why You Should Use Them](https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/02/08/microservices-what-they-are-why-to-use-them/).

**Lambda**

Microservices aside, as @Ashan suggested, for low ongoing cost you may want to look at functional programming/lambda architecture and [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/). Again - there is a complexity (since you go one level deeper in separating your deployment packages than with microservices) that is partially addressed by the serverless framework, but you have tools like [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)/Azure Functions/Google Functions to run your functions as a service and pay per use (real use, not reservation as in EC2).

**Microservices with Docker and AWS ECS**

If you want to stick to microservices, please look into [Docker and Amazon EC2 Container Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). This will allow you to effectively use AWS EC2 instances for running multiple microservices. You may want to put [Application Gateway in front of AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/microservice-delivery-with-amazon-ecs-and-application-load-balancers/) to manage the traffic.

Comment: Hi @Lech according to my knowledge and experience Lambda can immensely scale and support very high loads, so it will also fit into high traffic web solutions.

Comment: @Ashan, thank you for pointing this out. Yes, I am 100% with you, based on my experience lambda scales really (really really) well :) I am not sure how suggestion that lambda is for low traffic ended up there. Corrected already!

Comment: @Ashan While Lambda can definitely scale and support high loads it gets extremely expensive when you are running high loads on Lambda. At a certain point of scale it becomes far cheaper to run a persistent server process that can handle requests. There are a few reasons for this such as the fact that Lambda charges 100ms min for each invoke, even if your endpoint takes say 50ms to respond. So there is a lot of waste, versus a persistent node service running on a box can handle 1000's of concurrent requests for a fraction of the cost.

Answer (score 2):

AWS [serverless stack](https://medium.com/@middlechild/aws-serverless-stack-in-a-nutshell-aee963decdb8) will give you the lowest total cost of ownership for a Microservices project.

It mainly involves AWS API Gateway and Lambda where you will pay only for the Opex rather Capex.